# Does a slung Magic Stone have the same normal and long range as a mundane bullet?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *Magic Stone* cantrip (PotA p.238/[EEPC](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/princes-apocalypse) p.20) says:

> You touch one to three pebbles and imbue them with magic.  You or someone else can make a ranged spell attack with one of the pebbles by throwing it or hurling it with a sling.  If thrown, it has a range of 60 feet.

If sling is used to launch one of the pebbles, is the range 30/120, or just 120?

Comment: This question was also asked on Twitter: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/07/27/what-is-the-range-on-a-magic-stone-when-hurled-from-a-sling/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As nothing special is indicated for hurling the bullet with a sling, the normal rules for sling  range apply: **30/120**.

Answer (score 0):

### 120 feet (probably)

D&D 5e has two different kinds of range. *Weapon range* (expressed as *short range/maximum range* - PHB 147), and *spell range* (expressed as a single value - PHB 202-203 and in spell descriptions).

A thrown stone, as an improvised weapon (PHB 147-148) has the *weapon range* of 20/60.

A Magic Stone, as per the spell's description has a *spell range* of 60 feet. So we can infer that **the *spell range* of a thrown Magic Stone equals the *maximum range* of a normal thrown stone.**

If we extend this to using the Magic Stone as ammunition for a sling, it would seem reasonable to apply the same principle, and say that **the sling stone's *maximum range* of 120 feet is the *spell range* of a Magic Stone thrown from a sling.**

I say *probably* as this is an extension of the *principles* of the RAW, but as far as I know this principle is not spelled out in the currently-published rules.

Comment: I marked the 30/120 answer as accepted since this was tagged as a rules-as-written question, but I completely agree with your appeal to consistency.  It'd be 120 at my table.

Comment: I'd probably houserule it this way, too. If hurled by a sling, it should not be worse than thrown by hand.

Comment: Sebkha and @nvoigt - good to know. I realised I was being a bit more creative than RAW often allow, though looking at the definition on rpg.se I'm not sure if I've actually missed the mark, as the tag definition is "Interpretations and applications of rules that only take into consideration specifically what published game material states," and what I tried to do here was interpret and apply the published rules. I suppose the limits of interpretation and application are also subject to interpretation :-)